# mongoose search by a property in a json object field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I have a schema as

```
var TempSchema = new Schema({
    location: Schema.Types.Mixed
});
```

location will store a json object

now I want to search by a property inside this json object field, can I use following query ?

```
Temp.find({location.country: {$in: ['US', 'CN', 'JP']}});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can do it using [the dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#match-a-field-without-specifying-array-index), just enclose it inside quotes:

```
Temp.find({"location.country": {$in: ['US', 'CN', 'JP']}}, function(err, data) { /* ... */});
```